# Tinymce button is not visible for a theme

Tags: themes

I am using a plugin(https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-editor-custom-buttons/) which generate custom button on wp_editor. 
here is partial plugin code(I guess this code is responsible to generate button):

```
    /************************************************************************
     *
     *  Generate Visual Editor Button JS-files
     *
     ************************************************************************/

    if($selection == "wrap") {

    $custom= false;
    $first = substr($icon,0,1);
    if ($first == "_") {
    $icon = substr($icon, 1);
    $custom= true;
    }

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
        $uploaddir = $uploads['basedir']."/vecb/";
        $uploadurl = $uploads['baseurl']."/vecb/";

    $current = "// JavaScript Document

    function getBaseURL () {
       return location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname +
          (location.port && ':' + location.port) + '/';
    }

    (function() {
        tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.vecb_button".$count."', {
            init : function(ed, url) {
                ed.addButton('vecb_button".$count."', {
                    title : '".get_the_title()."',";
          if($custom == false) {
          $current .="image : url+'/icons/".$icon."',";
          } else {
          $current .="image : '".$uploadurl.$icon."',";
          }
          $current .=          "onclick : function() {
                         ed.selection.setContent('". $left_tag . "' + ed.selection.getContent() + '". $right_tag ."');
                    }
                });
            },
            createControl : function(n, cm) {
                return null;
            },
        });
        tinymce.PluginManager.add('vecb_button".$count."', tinymce.plugins.vecb_button".$count.");
    })();";

    } else {

    $custom= false;
    $first = substr($icon,0,1);
    if ($first == "_") {
    $icon = substr($icon, 1);
    $custom= true;
    }

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
        $uploaddir = $uploads['basedir']."/vecb/";
        $uploadurl = $uploads['baseurl']."/vecb/";

    $current = "// JavaScript Document

    function getBaseURL () {
       return location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname +
          (location.port && ':' + location.port) + '/';
    }

    (function() {
        tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.vecb_button".$count."', {
            init : function(ed, url) {
                ed.addButton('vecb_button".$count."', {
                    title : '".get_the_title()."',";
          if($custom == false) {
          $current .="image : url+'/icons/".$icon."',";
          } else {
          $current .="image : '".$uploadurl.$icon."',";
          }
          $current .=          "onclick : function() {
                         ed.selection.setContent('".$block_content."');
                    }
                });
            },
            createControl : function(n, cm) {
                return null;
            },
        });
        tinymce.PluginManager.add('vecb_button".$count."', tinymce.plugins.vecb_button".$count.");
    })();";

    }




$style .= $styling . "

";

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

But this button is not being shown for a theme developed by me. But it works fine in others theme.

The following screenshot is taken when Twenty Fifteen theme is active. 
[image]

The following screenshot is taken when my theme is active. 
[image]

And this is the functions.php file of my theme:

```
/*
##############################
General Configuration
##############################
*/
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

register_nav_menus( array(
    'top' => 'Primary Top Menu',
    'left' => 'Secondary Left Menu'
) );

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Whats wrong with my theme? It kills my whole day. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is your theme a child theme?

Comment: No. This theme is developed fromsratch using bootstrap.

Comment: How does the plugin add the buttons? Can you show the code for that?

Comment: Please see the update of my question.